# Is it better to have one method which can return a value irrelevant to the objective of the method or two separate methods named accordingly?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm currently working on a uni assignment where I know design is critical to the marking criteria.

The objective is to basically read a text file and return a count of the occurance of each word. There are a few small requirements including implementing a binary tree (of class word which has a string for the word and a count of its occurances) and having a count of the total number of words in the text file.

While I am filling the tree, I can keep a count of the number of words I have read. My method fillTree can return the number of words in the file without having to iterate through it a second time, but obviously the method name does not correlate with it at all and we have been taught that a method should do ONE thing only. Is it better to keep these two processes separate or leave it as it is? Or do I need to rethink my whole approach altogether?

Please bear with me as this is my first question here on SO. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we have been taught that a method should do ONE thing only

Pretty much. Unfortunately, programs are more complex than this. If you took this idea to the extreme, methods would have no parameters ;) So you need to factor in convenience and usability when writing an interface and when writing your programs. This requires consideration but it gets easier the more experience you have, and the better you understand the problem you are solving, as well as how any clients will use the interface.

In this case, the word count and the separate word count are really distinct. Consider: how shall you parameterize it into one method? what special odd qualifier shall you use to mean "all words"? `NULL` or an empty string would be a common choice in a C interface, and even in some C++ interfaces. However, I don't think this is a well designed interface (some will disagree).

IMO, the ideal interface would have two separate methods:

```
size_t wordCount() const;
size_t countOccurrencesOfWord(const std::string& pWord) const;
```

And the interface I discouraged earlier is:

```
// eah, just pass NULL or an empty string for the word count of the text file
size_t countOccurrencesOfWord(const std::string* const pWord) const;
```

However, another consideration is public versus private interface. Your public interface may provide 2 methods, but if the internal implementation may choose the same underlying implementation in some cases, or with slight variations when the problem is similar. Suppose your class wrapped a C interface which had that `size_t SomeTypeCountOccurrencesOfWord(SomeTypePtr pSomeType, const char* const pWord);` which permitted the `NULL` parameter `pWord` -- then two separate methods are still a good choice, even though their underlying implementation is almost identical.

The approach I would take initially would be to first populate the tree, then provide the necessary interface to count a word or all words. Then if I determined caching a value would be a good idea, I could easily introduce a variable after the fact.

Comment: thanks for that! I guess I was falling for ease and convenience and I really didn't want to iterate through it a second time, but I definitely see why now :)

Comment: @RYUUSEiiSTAR you're welcome. i have added a note about that. if you find these operations are slow, the data structure itself could be optimized in several ways. first get the implementation correct, then speed it up where necessary (generally: some optimizations can be written in initially if you understand the problem/execution well).

Answer (score 2):

There is often a tension between elegance and performance.

Suppose that you have a function `std::map<std::string, size_t> computeStatistics(std::istream& input)` which parses the input stream and count the occurrence of each word, storing them into the `map`.

Then you can implement:

- `size_t countOccurrencesOfWord(std::string const& word, std::istream& input)`, as parsing and then looking up into the map.
- `size_t countWords(std::istream& input)`, as parsing and then summing up the counts.

Each method has a single responsibility, but there is a lot of duplicate work. I would suggest exposing the intermediate step instead:

```
class FileStatistics;

FileStatistics computeStatistics(std::istream& input);
```

and this class can expose simple methods:

```
size_t FileStatistics::getOccurrencesOfWord(std::string const& word) const;
size_t FileStatistics::getTotalNumberOfWords() const;
```

And internally, you can choose how it is structured. My recommendation would be a `std::map<std::string, size_t>` for the occurrences and just a `size_t` for the total.

Answer (score 0):

Having two separate methods named will be better in long term for code maintenance. If in future someone have to carry this project in your absence, unique name and functionality will help him to understand and debug easier. That is why it is advised to have one method to do one thing only and the method name should be able to give developer idea on what it actually does.

Comment: I agree, but I'd also cache the count since you have it anyway.  Saves having to do it again when you need it.

Comment: Yes . that's right. there can be another unique function just to do that

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you want to ask what the return value of `fillTree` ought to be. Most likely a success code.

Do you need to keep track of the element count or not? If so, I would have thought storing that directly in the data structure would be the thing to do.

Having said that, *if it makes the code simpler and easier to read*, `fillTreeAndReturnElementsStored` is certainly not an unreasonable approach.

Comment: I need to do both, count how many times the word appears as well as how many words in the whole file there is. I am storing the word count in my object already, just need a way of counting all the words as well

Answer (score 0):

Stick on to single responsibility principle (a class or method should do one thing and one thing only). Having two methods as suggested by others would be a better design.

One of the main problem with lots of software projects is that they not only violate single responsibility principle but by doing so they end up violating [open-closed principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/ocp.pdf).